# How to query posts using GET with numeric values within a given range?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to give my visitors and option to choose specific products within the selected price range.

```
<select name="retail_price" class="form-control">
<option disabled selected value="">Price up to</option>
<?php for ($i=1;$i<=45;$i++): ?>
<option value="<?= $i*1000 ?>">to $<?= number_format($i*1000,0,'',' ') ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

E.g. if they select "up to $1 000" and click "Search" button they will be taken to https://example.com/?retail_price=1000. On this page I would like to display stock within the given price range: up to $1000, up to $2000 etc etc etc.

`functions.php` contains:

```
$metaQuery = [];
        (...)

    if ( isset( $_GET['retail_price'] ) ) {

        $metaQuery[] = [
        'key'     => 'retail_price',
        'value'   => $_GET['retail_price'],
        'compare' => '='
        ];

        }


$query->set('meta_query', $metaQuery);
```

Any advice?

**Edit**:
Sorted using avice from @Sky.

```
        if ( isset( $_GET['retail_price'] ) ) {
        $metaQuery[] = [
        'key'     => 'retail_price',
        'value'   => array( '0', $_GET['retail_price'] ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ];
```

Comment: Your query should be something like: SELECT * FROM products WHERE retail_price < 1000. I'm not really sure how your querybuilder works

Comment: Using `'compare' => '<='` with your example is not giving you the desired result?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215519/76745)

Comment: @sky sorted, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted using advice from @Sky.

```
        if ( isset( $_GET['retail_price'] ) ) {
        $metaQuery[] = [
        'key'     => 'retail_price',
        'value'   => array( '0', $_GET['retail_price'] ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ];
```

Did the trick. Thank you all for your help :)